# Adding eslint-webpack-plugin into project to provide Typescript linting

Tags: webpack, eslint, typescript-eslint

I am having a hard time plugging a Typescript linter in my Webpack project.

Apparently [`eslint-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/eslint-loader) is deprecated, they give [`eslint-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/eslint-webpack-plugin) as an alternative. Additionally, I am using [`typescript-eslint/parser`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint) instead of [`tslint`](https://github.com/palantir/tslint) (*deprecated*) The problem is the rules I set inside my `.eslintrc.js` don't seem to get accounted for. I have added a simple rule in `.eslintrc` that should throw an error when using a semicolon.

```js
export default class A {
  static yes = 'this is static'; // ";" <- should be invalidated by eslint
}
```

My dependencies are:

```js
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.5.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.5.0",
"eslint": "^7.11.0",
"eslint-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
"ts-loader": "^8.0.6",
"typescript": "^4.0.3",
"webpack": "^4.41.3",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0"
```

If I understand correctly it should work like so:

```
                                                        # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 
@typescript-eslint/parser --> eslint-webpack-plugin --> #                         # 
      (uses eslint?)        (replaces eslint-loader)    #       webpack v4        #
                                                        #  w/ webpack-dev-server  #
       typescript         -->       ts-loader       --> #                         #
                                                        # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
```

Side note: *I'm using `webpack-dev-server` instead of [`webpack-cli`](https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/)'s serve command which [doesn't seem to work quite yet with `webpack` v5](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/2759)*.

The command I run to launch the server: `webpack-dev-server --hot --inline`

[image]

---

- project structure:

```MD
./
├─── src
│    └─── index.ts
└─── dist
     ├─── bundle.js
     └─── index.html <- imports bundle.js
```

- **webpack.config.js**:

```js
const path = require('path')
const ESLintPlugin = require('eslint-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    // publicPath: "/assets", // path of the served resources (js, img, fonts...)
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new ESLintPlugin({
      files: 'src/**/*.ts',
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
}
```

- **.eslintrc.js**:

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true,
  },
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  extends: [
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended'
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2020,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  rules: {
    'semi': ['error', 'never'],
  },
  ignorePatterns: [ "dist/*" ],
}
```

- **tsconfig.json**:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I experienced a similar issue when trying to use the `eslint-webpack-plugin` with `.vue` files.

My solution was to use the `extensions` setting instead of `files`. Try this:

```js
new ESLintPlugin({
  extensions: ['ts']
})
```

Comment: Also it'd be helpful to [the documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/developer-guide/nodejs-api#-new-eslintoptions) that described all options for **eslint-webpack-plugin**, that says:  
`options.extensions (string[] | null)
For example, when passing the src/ directory and extensions is [".js", ".ts"], ESLint will lint *.js and *.ts files in src/. If extensions is null, ESLint checks *.js files and files that match overrides[].files patterns in your configuration.
Note: This option only applies when you pass directory paths to the eslint.lintFiles() method.`

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this and my current ESLintPlugin options object is the following:

```
const lintJSOptions = {
  context: path.join(paths.context, paths.js),
  extensions: ['js', 'ts'],
  emitError: true,
  emitWarning: true,
  failOnWarning: false,
  failOnError: false,
  // Toggle autofix
  fix: false,
  cache: false,

  formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter'),
};
```

Hope this helps.

PD: `context` property is the root location of your *.js or *.ts files relative to your `package.json` file, you can use `path.resolve(__dirname, './src/scripts');` or wherever you store your scripts instead.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue while trying to setup slit with Webpack. I solved it by using override config inside Webpack

```
plugins: [
    new ESLintPlugin({
      files: 'src/**/*.ts',
      "overrideConfig": {
        "extends": "eslint:recommended",
        "rules": { }
      }
    })
  ],
```

You can find it here in the official eslint documentation
https://eslint.org/docs/latest/developer-guide/nodejs-api#-new-eslintoptions

Comment: you are a life saver... I've tried dozens of solutions, yours was the only one that worked. thank you!